# Getting the OutOfMemoryError when generating a Cartesian product of large lists

Tags: java, list, out-of-memory, cartesian-product

I'm trying to generate a Cartesian product of List in Java with this code:

```java
private static List<List<String>> getCartesian(List<List<String>> initialList) {
    List<List<String>> result = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    result.add(new ArrayList<String>());
    for (List<String> first : initialList) {
        List<List<String>> temporaryList = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
        for (List<String> second : result) {
            for (String word : first) {
                List<String> tmp2 = new ArrayList<String>(second);
                tmp2.add(word);
                temporaryList.add(tmp2);
            }
        }
        result = temporaryList;
    }
    return result;
}
```

I am getting the following error when I using large lists:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

What can I do to make it work on big data?

Comment: See JVM option -Xmx.

Comment: Do you need to have all those lists in memory at the same time? What are you going to do with the product when you have made it?

Comment: Run Java with the command-line option -Xmx, which sets the maximum size of the heap. Default is 512M I think, thus be aware: you are using a lot of memory for this function...

Comment: I tried to Increase JVM Heap Size, but no result. For each these cartesian I make this: `java.util.List<java.util.List<String>> allCombinations=cartesianProduct(subsequence1);
 int [] scoreList=new int[allCombinations.size()];
            for(int i=0;i<allCombinations.size();i++)    scoreList[i]= getScore(allCombinations.get(i));` How can I modify this method to get only this `scoreList`.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to avoid using `ArrayList` for things like this. All of the information needed to generate the result is contained in the original `List<List<String>>`, so there is no need to have all of the answers in memory all at the same time.

The following code produces a list equal to `getCartesian`, but it does not store it all in one big `ArrayList`. Instead, it makes a copy of all the original lists and computes a single answer when requested.

```
public static List<List<String>> getCartesian2(List<List<String>> lists) {
    long size = 1;
    final List<List<String>> copy = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    for (List<String> list : lists) {
        size *= list.size();
        if (size > Integer.MAX_VALUE)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        copy.add(new ArrayList<String>(list));
    }
    final int fSize = (int) size;
    return new AbstractList<List<String>>() {
        @Override
        public int size() {
            return fSize;
        }
        @Override
        public List<String> get(int i) {
            if (i < 0 || i >= fSize)
                throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
            String[] arr = new String[copy.size()];
            for (int j = copy.size() - 1; j >= 0; j--)  {
                List<String> list = copy.get(j);
                arr[j] = list.get(i % list.size());
                i /= list.size();
            }
            return Arrays.asList(arr);
        }
    };
}
```